# Syntax for adding static resources to an ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, staticresource, objectdataprovider

I'm creating several static resources that I want to add to an ObjectDataProvider, but I can't figure out the syntax.

```
 <Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidFillBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="1.0" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HalfOpaqueBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="QuarterOpaqueBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="0.25" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="0" />

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AllFillStyles" ObjectType="{x:Type Brush}" MethodName="???">
         <!-- add the static resources here, but how?  -->
    </ObjectDataProvider>

 </Window.Resources>
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:  I was trying to create a ComboBox containing the above Brushes, so the user could select which brush to use as the fill style for a grid (kind of like in Excel, where you can choose the fill style and color.)  I needed to set the ItemsSource, and found where someone had used the ObjectDataProvider.  I figured out that you could create an Array in the xaml and fill it with the brushes, then use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

A sample one on how to use `ObjectDataProvider`. `MethodName` is the name of the Method it will try to call when getting the items

in your **xaml file**

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="objDs"
                             ObjectType="{x:Type data:CDataAccess}"
                             MethodName="GetEmployees">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

And your **class file**

```
public class CDataAccess
{
    ObservableCollection<ImageEmployee> _EmpCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<ImageEmployee> EmpCollection
    {
        get { return _EmpCollection; }
        set { _EmpCollection = value; }
    }

    public CDataAccess()
    {
        _EmpCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImageEmployee>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ImageEmployee> GetEmployees()
    {
        SqlConnection conn =
        new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Company;" +
                            "Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from ImageEmployee";

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            EmpCollection.Add(
                new ImageEmployee()
                {
                    EmpNo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmpNo"]),
                    EmpName = reader["EmpName"].ToString(),
                    Salary = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Salary"]),
                    DeptNo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DeptNo"]),
                    EmpImage = (byte[])reader["EmpImage"]
                });
        }
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return EmpCollection;
    }
}
```

If your `MethodName` has a parameter, you can add this to your resource object provider

```
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters> 
                 <s:String>Parameter1</s:String> 
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```

and make sure your parameter types are matching it.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what is yout real goal with ObjectDataProvider.

If you want call some method on object AllFillStyle with different parameter which identify resource key (SolidColorBrush object).

For example:

- AllFileStyle.GetBrush("SolidFillBrush")
- AllFileStyle.GetBrush("HalfOpaqueBrush")
- etc

it is not easy because will [need pass paramater dynamically to ObjectDataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882462/how-to-pass-value-to-objectdataprovider-methodparameters-dynamically-in-runtime).

If you only need group all resouces type of SolidColorBrush and use in XAML.

You can populate all resources type of SolidColorBrush in code.

```
private ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> _windowBrushes;

public ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> WindowBrushes
{
    get
    {
        return _windowBrushes;
    }

    set
    {
        _windowBrushes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("WindowBrushes");
    }
}


private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowBrushes = new ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>();

    foreach (var resource in this.Resources.Values)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = resource as SolidColorBrush;

        if (brush!=null)
        {
            WindowBrushes.Add(brush);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use in XAML.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxBrushes"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Margin="5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WindowBrushes, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse Width="30"
                         Height="30"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         StrokeThickness="1"
                         Fill="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Rectangle Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="5"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           Fill="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxBrushes, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Could you specify your scenario with ObjectDataProvider?

Thank